# NoSuchMethodError 'void <init>()' when Testing an injected Kotlin class with Provider Injection using the QuarkusTestExtension

Tags: gradle, kotlin, dependency-injection, quarkus

I've got a simple test to test a class in a Quarkus application (using kotlin and gradle), which fails when directly injecting the class being tested, but succeeds when instantiating it.

The weird thing is that it only happens in the CI, or when debugging it in the IDE (Intellij) - not when executing it via ./gradlew check, nor when running it without debugging in the IDE.

Fails:

```
@QuarkusTest
class InfluxVehicleRepositoryTest
@Inject constructor(private val influxVehicleRepository: InfluxVehicleRepository) {
    @Test
    fun findByMinutesFromNow() {
        val result = influxVehicleRepository.findByMinutesFromNow(5)

        assertThat(result).isEmpty()
    }
}
```

Succeeds:

```
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(InfluxDBResource::class)
class InfluxVehicleRepositoryTest
@Inject constructor(private val influxDBProvider: InfluxDBProvider) {
    @Test
    fun findByMinutesFromNow() {
        val influxVehicleRepository = InfluxVehicleRepository(influxDBProvider)
        val result = influxVehicleRepository.findByMinutesFromNow(5)

        assertThat(result).isEmpty()
    }
}
```

The class being tested as well as its direct dependency look like that:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class InfluxVehicleRepository
private constructor(private val influxDB: InfluxDB) : VehicleRepository {
    @Inject
    constructor (influxDBProvider: InfluxDBProvider) : this(influxDBProvider.get())
    ...
}

...

@ApplicationScoped
class InfluxDBProvider : Provider<InfluxDB> {
    @ConfigProperty(name = "traffic.influx.username", defaultValue = "admin")
    lateinit var username: String
    ...

    override fun get(): InfluxDB {
        ...
        return influxDb
    }
}
```

Here is the log of the gradle test execution:

```
Testing started at 13:11 ...
> Task :cleanTest
> Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :quarkusTestConfig
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/home/chris/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/2.5.8/2f1e8ea55e625fe51e85ef35eb067f1d9c61772d/groovy-2.5.8.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:02 PM org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$1
INFO: Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:03 PM org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy test
INFO: Found docker client settings from environment
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:03 PM org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$2
INFO: Found Docker environment with Environment variables, system properties and defaults. Resolved dockerHost=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:03 PM org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory client
INFO: Docker host IP address is localhost
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:03 PM org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory client
INFO: Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 19.03.6-ce
  API Version: 1.40
  Operating System: Manjaro Linux
  Total Memory: 11908 MB
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:04 PM org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory client
INFO: Ryuk started - will monitor and terminate Testcontainers containers on JVM exit
        ℹ︎ Checking the system...
        ✔ Docker version should be at least 1.6.0
        ✔ Docker environment should have more than 2GB free disk space
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:04 PM org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer tryStart
INFO: Creating container for image: influxdb:1.4.3
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:04 PM org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer tryStart
INFO: Starting container with ID: 9b84011b121fd153d81299d6b25ad4c9cf000524fb37cd8e591fcf233123bb39
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:04 PM org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer tryStart
INFO: Container influxdb:1.4.3 is starting: 9b84011b121fd153d81299d6b25ad4c9cf000524fb37cd8e591fcf233123bb39
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:04 PM org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.HttpWaitStrategy waitUntilReady
INFO: /sharp_dirac: Waiting for 30 seconds for URL: http://localhost:32830/ping
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:08 PM org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer tryStart
INFO: Container influxdb:1.4.3 started in PT5.352938S
Mar 06, 2020 1:11:08 PM org.jboss.threads.Version <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Threads version 3.0.0.Final
[0K[1mde.flick.traffic.vehicles.InfluxVehicleRepositoryTest[m
[0K[1m  Test [22mfindByMinutesFromNow()[31m FAILED[31m
  org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: TestInstanceFactory [io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension] failed to instantiate test class [de.flick.traffic.vehicles.InfluxVehicleRepositoryTest]
  Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize Arc
  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: de.flick.traffic.vehicles.InfluxVehicleRepository: method 'void <init>()' not found
[m

TestInstanceFactory [io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension] failed to instantiate test class [de.flick.traffic.vehicles.InfluxVehicleRepositoryTest]
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: TestInstanceFactory [io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension] failed to instantiate test class [de.flick.traffic.vehicles.InfluxVehicleRepositoryTest]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstanceFactory(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:300)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:275)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:416)
    at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:153)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:249)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.createTestInstance(QuarkusTestExtension.java:394)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstanceFactory(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:285)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:406)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize Arc
    at io.quarkus.arc.Arc.initialize(Arc.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcRecorder.getContainer(ArcRecorder.java:34)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources26.deploy_0(ArcProcessor$generateResources26.zig:72)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ArcProcessor$generateResources26.deploy(ArcProcessor$generateResources26.zig:36)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(ApplicationImpl.zig:360)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: de.flick.traffic.vehicles.InfluxVehicleRepository: method 'void <init>()' not found
    at de.flick.traffic.vehicles.InfluxVehicleRepository_ClientProxy.<init>(InfluxVehicleRepository_ClientProxy.zig:129)
    at de.flick.traffic.vehicles.InfluxVehicleRepository_Bean.<init>(InfluxVehicleRepository_Bean.zig:218)
    at io.quarkus.arc.setup.Default_ComponentsProvider.addBeans1(Default_ComponentsProvider.zig:1074)
    at io.quarkus.arc.setup.Default_ComponentsProvider.getComponents(Default_ComponentsProvider.zig:38)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.<init>(ArcContainerImpl.java:103)
    at io.quarkus.arc.Arc.initialize(Arc.java:20)
    ... 82 more

[0K[1;31mFAILURE: [39mExecuted 1 tests in 8.7s (1 failed)[m
1 test completed, 1 failed
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/chris/dev/ConnectedVehicle/project/cvs/manage-vehicle-data/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 9s
6 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

So my questions is why does the first version fail (not in all cases) and the second does not?

Setup:

- Gradle: 6.0.1
- Quarkus: 1.2.1.Final
- JDK: OpenJDK 13
- sourceCompatibility: JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
- targetCompatibility: JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
- OS: Manjaro Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug within the classloader of Quarkus that is going to be fixed in the following Quarkus release 1.3.0.

For more information see the related GitHub issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7710